# No module named urllib.parse

Tags: python, twitter

Pythonのvirtualenvにpipで`Tweepy`をインストールしようとしたのですが､以下の様なエラーがでました｡  `Tweepy`のインストール時に一緒にインストールされた`six`というライブラリが原因だと思うのですが､対処方法がわかりません｡

**エラー**

```html
(env) D:\>python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tweepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Documents\env\lib\site-packages\tweepy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tweepy.models import Status, User, DirectMessage, Friendship, SavedSearch, SearchResults, M
odelFactory, Category
  File "D:\Documents\env\lib\site-packages\tweepy\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tweepy.utils import parse_datetime, parse_html_value, parse_a_href
  File "D:\Documents\env\lib\site-packages\tweepy\utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.parse import quote
ImportError: No module named urllib.parse
```

**pip freeze**

```html
(env) D:\>pip freeze
matplotlib==1.2.0
nltk==3.0.2
numpy==1.9.2
oauthlib==0.7.2
PyYAML==3.11
requests==2.6.0
requests-oauthlib==0.4.2
scikit-learn==0.15.2
scipy==0.12.0
six==1.9.0
tweepy==3.3.0
```

対処方法を教えて下さい｡

**追記**

シェルで`six`のヴァージョンを表示させてみたところ､`pip freeze`で表示したのとなぜか違います｡

```html
(env) D:\>python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import six
>>> six.__version__
'1.2.0-mpl'
```

**追記**

1､ アンインストールして`easy_install`でインストールを試みると以下のエラーで失敗しました｡

**エラー(easy_install使用時)**

```html
(env) D:\>python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tweepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\models.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\utils.py", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urllib.parse
```

2､ `matplotlib`の中に`six`があるみたいなのですが､もしかしてこれを参照している??

```html
>>> import six
>>> six.__version__
'1.2.0-mpl'
>>> six
<module 'six' from 'D:\Documents\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-win32.egg\six.pyc'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました｡

`matplotlib`の中に古いバージョンの`six`があり､`tweepy`がそれを参照しているようでした｡  `matplotlib`をインストールし直したところ治りました｡

Answer (score 1):

sixはPython2とPython3のライブラリ構成の違いを吸収するための抽象ライブラリです。tweepyはsixを使ってPython2/3両対応しているのでしょう。

今回の問題は、既に書かれているとおり、matplotlibが古いsixを持っていたためのようですが、インストール時に最新版をインストールする `-U` オプションを付けていれば問題にならなかったのだと思います。そういう意味では、tweeepyがsixのバージョンいくつ以上を必要としているのかを明示していなかったのが問題だったのだと思います。

依存バージョンを含めて最新バージョンをインストールするには以下のようにすればよかったのでしょう。

```
pip install -U tweepy
```

なお、質問されるときは、インストール手順を最初から（matplotlibをどうやってインストールしているのかを含めて）書くとアドバイスしやすいかと思います。また、easy_installコマンドは現在はあまり使う必要がないはずで、pipコマンドだけで十分だと思われます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます｡  勉強になります｡  `matplotlib`を最初にインストールした時に`pip`ではなくバイナリからインストールしたので､古いバージョンの`six`がインストールされていたのだと思います｡  アドバイスありがとうございます｡